# Efficiently dealing with multiple "similar" events

Tags: c#, events, xna-4.0

In my C#/XNA project, I have a "static" class that manages the input. It looks like this:

```
internal sealed class InputManager
{
    public delegate void KeyboardHandler(Actions action);

    public static event KeyboardHandler KeyPressed;

    private static readonly Dictionary<Actions, Keys> KeyBindings = Main.ContentManager.Load<Dictionary<Actions, Keys>>("KeyBindings");

    private static KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;

    private InputManager()
    {
    }

    public static void GetInput()
    {
        currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Actions, Keys> actionKeyPair in KeyBindings)
        {
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(actionKeyPair.Value))
            {
                OnKeyPressed(actionKeyPair.Key);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnKeyPressed(Actions action)
    {
        if (KeyPressed != null)
        {
            KeyPressed(action);
        }
    }
}
```

So throughout the game, I get the input and check if any key contained in my dictionary is currently pressed (I use a dictionary for key binding purpose - an action is bound to a key). If so, the KeyPressed event is fired with the associated action as argument. By doing this I can subscribe an external class (such as a camera) to this event and do the appropriate thing based on the action (key).

The problem is that I have to test the action in every subscriber's method like this:

```
        if (action == Actions.MoveLeft)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
```

Hence, no matter which key is pressed (as long as it's part of the dictionary) every subscriber's method will be called even if it actually doesn't need to.

I know I could set an event for each action : event MoveLeft, event MoveRight, etc... However, is there a better way to do this like a list of event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use interface to deal with:
for instance:

```
interface IExecuteAction
{
void doMoveLeftAction();
void doMoveRightAction(); 
}

ExecuteMoveLeftAction(Actions action,IExecuteAction execAction)
{
switch(action
 case Actions.MoveLeft :
        execAction.doMoveLeftAction(); 
        break; 
case Actions.MoveLeft :
        execAction.doMoveLeftAction(); 
        break;
}
```

in your code implement this interface on your subscriber

```
class subscriber1:IExecuteAction
{
void doMoveLeftAction()
{
//do what you want
}
void doMoveRightAction()
 {
 //do what you want
 }
}
```

and after you handle like this:

```
ExecuteMoveLeftAction(action,subscriber1);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this way! I've set my mind too much on using events to keep subscriber's method private, but at least, with an interface, the methods are called only when necessary. Anyway, I don't think it would've been possible without setting one event + one method to trigger that event per action which I want to avoid.